# Scrollable Div via buttons and no scroll-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I know this topic has been covered numerous times, but everything I've viewed and tried just isn't quite working. Hoping that providing my actual code will result in a solution. I've got the scrolling up to work, but the down button is doing nothing. Attempting to use the buttons to scroll within this "homeBlogs" div only. Here is the code i'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#upClick").click(function() {
    $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop($('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() + 400);
  });

  $("#downClick").click(function() {
    $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop($('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() - 800);
  });

});
```

```css
#homeBlogs {
  background-color: #878787;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#scrollUp {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#scrollDown {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <div class="row" id="scrollUp">
    <button id="downClick"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="homeBlogs">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="blogTitle">Blog Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="blogFeed1">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="thumbNail1" />
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="blogTitle">Blog Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="blogFeed2">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="thumbNail2" />
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="blogTitle">Blog Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="blogFeed3">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="thumbNail3" />
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="scrollDown">
    <button id="downClick"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The #downClick "click" event is never being triggered - it looks like it's visible but the #homeBlogs element is covering it, meaning it never actually gets clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two buttons with an id of downClick, and no buttons with an id of upClick.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#upClick").click(function() {
    console.log('Before:'+$('#homeBlogs').scrollTop());
    $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop($('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() + 400);
    console.log('After:'+$('#homeBlogs').scrollTop());
  });

  $("#downClick").click(function() {
    console.log('Before:'+$('#homeBlogs').scrollTop());
    $('#homeBlogs').scrollTop($('#homeBlogs').scrollTop() - 800);
    console.log('After:'+$('#homeBlogs').scrollTop());
  });

});
```

```css
#homeBlogs {
  background-color: #878787;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#scrollUp {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#scrollDown {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <div class="row" id="scrollUp">
    <button id="downClick"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="homeBlogs">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="blogTitle">Blog Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="blogFeed1">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="thumbNail1" />
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="blogTitle">Blog Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="blogFeed2">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="thumbNail2" />
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="blogTitle">Blog Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="blogFeed3">
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="thumbNail3" />
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="scrollDown">
    <button id="downClick"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I shoulda been on top of that copy/past error! This was all a tremendous help, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This is the best starting point I can make for you, there are some issues with overlap but perhaps this can help?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on( "click", "#upClick", function() {
        var top = $("#blogFeed1").css('margin-top').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        $("#blogFeed1").css('margin-top', top+100+'px');
     }); 

    $(document).on( "click", "#downClick", function() {
        var top = $("#blogFeed1").css('margin-top').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        $("#blogFeed1").css('margin-top', top-100+'px');
     }); 

});
</script>
```